# I need to separate my main App from celery, in different servers. How could i achieve this goal?

Tags: django, docker, amazon-ec2, redis, celery

Today i have a AWS EC2 instance where i run my main App (Django). I'm using docker to containerize my services, which are: Django, Nginx, Mysql, Redis, Celery.
I now that all those services in one instance is the wrong path to follow and i want to make things right. I would like to start by separating the workers from my main App, because the App consumes a lot of processing in some tasks and i want to isolate those tasks from main App, in another server. Let's call it of Server B.

How could i achieve this, using a Server A, running the main App, and Server B, handling cpu bound tasks with celery? Did i was clear? Sorry about my english.